Constructing Confidence Intervals for MLE with a Restricted Parameter Space
The MLE of a $N(\theta, 1)$ distribution, when $(\theta >= 0)$, is given by $\hat{\theta}^{MLE} = \max(0, \bar{X})$. (The MLE of a $N(\theta, 1)$ distribution)
However, the regularity conditions for the asymptotic normality of the MLE are not satisfied in this case. (Consistency and asymptotic normality of MLE of $\theta$ in $N(\theta,1)$ when $\theta\ge 0$)
In a sample, a single observation $X_1 = -2$ was made.Now, I need to construct a 95% confidence interval for $\theta$. However, using the confidence interval formula for a normal distribution with known variance gives a strange result: (-3.96, -0.04), which contradicts the condition that $\theta >= 0$. Moreover, the asymptotic distribution of the MLE cannot be applied here for the reasons mentioned above.
So, how can I construct a confidence interval for $\theta$ in this case?

The link you provided to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541565/the-mle-of-a-n-theta-1-distribution, explains that the MLE must provide a $\ge 0$ result. Therefore, I believe you should investigate single-sided confidence intervals, i.e., intervals for nonnegative distributions, not ones based on normality.

I tried to calculate the distribution of $\theta$ from $x|\theta$ and $I{\theta \geq 0}$, but $I{\theta \geq 0}$ is not a probability distribution. Even if I construct some intervals for $\theta$ based on this, those intervals would only be credible sets.
I also attempted to make a transformation such that $P(0 < \theta < u(X)) = 0.95$, but this leads to $u(X) = X + 1.96$. Should I instead look for a transformation of $X$ that defines the boundary of $\theta$ for that probability?
